# what is the use of adding id in the html link tag

Tags: html, css

need to know why they added "ID" in this link tag

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='name-of-the-id'  href='style.css?ver=4.1.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Comment: who? please don't come with question like that which will not serve to future user or current community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id could be used for multiple things.

Out of this context I can't tell you which because you didn't provide more of the relevant page. However an id in a stylesheet link could be used with jquery to put the link in an object so you can change, lets say the location, or file or any of the other attributes of that link while keeping it distinct by use of the id.